# What's the difference between AssetImage and ExactAssetImage?

Tags: flutter

I am unable to understand the difference between `AssetImage` and `ExactAssetImage`. I can use

```
Image(
  image: AssetImage(chocolateImage),
)
```

Or

```
Image(
  image: ExactAssetImage(chocolateImage),
)
```

with no performance or memory difference. The only advantage `ExactAssetImage` has is the `scale` property, but is that all there to it? If yes, then what's the need of `AssetImage`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is related to the **images with different pixel densities** you provide in your assets list.

I mean when you have provided images like this:

```
icons/heart.png 
icons/1.5x/heart.png 
icons/2.0x/heart.png
```

If you use `AssetImage`, flutter will choose between your 3 images depending on the device density pixels.

> On a device with a 1.0 device pixel ratio, the image chosen would be
>   heart.png; on a device with a 1.3 device pixel ratio, the image chosen
>   would be 1.5x/heart.png.

---

If you use `ExactAssetImage`, you select the scale manually, doing somthing like:

```
Image(image: ExactAssetImage("your-asset",scale: 2)),
```

Comment: As you said, `On a device with a 1.0 device pixel ratio, the image chosen would be heart.png;` Will it take the image automatically If I defined the folder structure as given for `AssetImage`?

Answer (score 2):

**AssetImage**
    `AssetImage` fetches the image from the `AssetBundle` then uses the context to determine the exact image to use. Then based on the device pixel ratio and size determines the best configuration for the image this then get passed to `resolve` 
**ExactAssetImage**
`ExactAssetImage` fetches images in a similar way  while also associating a scale with the image. `ExactAssetImage` ignores the devices pixels ratio and size in the configuration passed to resolve.

**In Conclusion**
`AssetImage` is resolution-aware and can pick the right image based on the right device pixel ratio and size while `ExactAssetImage` is not. So to more directly answer your question `ExactAssetImage` gives you more control of memory usage as it will use the exact resolution of the image.